# Why is area negative with $\int_0^2 (x^2-3x)dx$

Tags: integration

When calculating this integral

$$\int_0^2 (x^2-3x)dx = \left [ \frac{x^3}{3}-1.5x^2\right ]_0^2 = \frac{8}{3}-6=-\frac{10}{3}$$

I would use $\frac{10}{3}$ as the result because the area can not be negative. But that seems to be wrong. Could someone explain me why? Obviously the funciton $x^2-3x$ for the interval [0,2] is in the negative range. But the area would still be positive?

thanks a lot

Comment: Think of the integral as a sum. You are summing a negative quantity, hence the answer is negative.

Comment: In general, a definite integral does not give an area. It does give the area "above the $x$-axis" plus the negative of the area below.

Comment: In general, if you want to find the geometric area between a function and its axis, you have to separate your definite integral into the parts above the axis and the parts below it. You sum the positive parts with the absolute value of the negative ones. This means that you always have to check the intersection of the function with its axis on the interval of integration.

Comment: Hi Olivier. True but in the intervall [0,2] the area is all negative?

Comment: If you'd want, you could separate your integral into one part and add it's absolute value to zero... But I think this is what you have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you calculate the area between the graphs of two function $f,g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ on an interval, where $f\le g$, you would do so by integrating
$$ A =\int_a^b (g(x)-f(x))\ \mathrm dx.$$
In this case, you want the area between the $x$-axis and $f(x)=x^2-3x$. The $x$-axis is described by $g(x)=0$. As you already noted, $f(x)\le 0$ for $x\in[0,2]$ in your case, so you get
$$A = \int_0^2 (\underbrace{g(x)}_0-f(x))\ \mathrm dx = \int_0^2 -f(x)\ \mathrm dx = -\int_0^2 f(x)\ \mathrm dx = +\frac{10}{3}.$$

Comment: Hi. Thanks this makes sense to me

Comment: ... **if** you want the geometric area,as usual many times in high school. The (algebraic or general) *area* can be negative, zero or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, the curve is entirely below the x-axis. When you compute the area by integration, you obtained the area between the curve and the x-axis. So, this area has a sign.

To illustrate this point using your function, if you integrate from $0$ to $a$, the result is a^2 (2 a -9) /6. This means that if  $a=9/2$, the area is just $0$. If you integrate for $a > 9/2$, the area becomes positive.

Is this making things clearer for you ?